# Do you treat "your own" first reflection points?

Tags: acoustics, room-treatment, psychoacoustics

It's well known that you should treat the first reflection points in your studio- i.e. the surfaces that reflect sound directly from your speakers to your ears.  My intuition says that you should also treat "your own" first reflection points, i.e. the surfaces that reflect sound directly from you to your ears, so that your listening environment is consistent.  I've recently read, though, that sometimes a design consideration of totally anechoic listening rooms is to *not* treat those spots, in order to make the space more comfortable to the listener.  Is there an established best practice or common practice with respect to treating these spots?

Comment: It’s not clear to me what you mean by ‘“your own” first reflection points’. Do you mean places on your body that reflect sound? Like… wearing some kind of shoulder pads or something?

Comment: "surfaces that reflect sound directly from you to your ears", like the ceiling right above you, the walls right beside you.

Comment: I still don't quite understand I think. What is the other source of sound that is not the speakers?

Comment: @ToddWilcox The listener.

Comment: "...directly from you to your ears" it does sound like it's reflecting off your body somehow. Are you producing the sounds?

Comment: I'm using "directly from you to your ears" in contrast to "directly from your speakers to your ears".  Yes, I am making these sounds.  Talking, sneezing, breathing, coughing, fidgeting, etc.

Answer (score 0):

### No

A) In smaller rooms, the place where sounds made by the listener reflect first and where the speakers reflect first might be close enough that treating the latter also treats the former.

B) There's not enough sound coming from listeners to make it worth the cost of additional treatment.

C) As you allude to, it's possible to make a room too dead.